# stop CaptureChangeMySQL when putSQL failed

Tags: apache-nifi

I use nifi to consume mysql binlog and relay sql in another database, just like MySQL slave replication, as binlog is sequential I want to stop `CaptureChangeMySQL` in case when `PutSQL` failed, so that data in target database in slave will not be messed.

I set all queues's backpressure object threshold all to be 1, but it does not work, still execute following sql statement when `PutSQL` failed executing current sql.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `Rollback On Failure = true`.  If enabled, failed FlowFiles will stay in the input relationship without penalizing it and being processed repeatedly until it gets processed successfully or removed by other means. It is important to set adequate 'Yield Duration' to avoid retrying too frequently.

this also will affect all backpressures and theoretically capture will stop.